# Spring boot app - thymeleaf loads pictures after a while. Some kind of cache problem?

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, templates, thymeleaf

I make a small web app.
I am fresh to Spring boot.
I work on Intellij
I've had a situation, that I 've created a small maze in a temlpate with thymeleaf.

I was confused, why the pictures didn't show up yesterday.
I gave up, turned the computer off.
Today I turn it on, run Intellij, run the app without changing everything just to check if everything 
runs ok, before coding.
What I see? -> The images I was fighting for has suddenly shown up... wtf???
I actually didn't do anything.
Why did it happen? ... 
Actually I have seen that the same things have happen with css background images when loading the app
Is it because of the cache?
And how to manage it?
I would like to understand it to save some time in the future.

```
<div class="captcha-field" id="top_left" th:if="${field.isEqualFieldType('TOP_LEFT')}">
         <img class="fill-img" th:src="@{/img/maze/TL.jpg}">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you restart the Spring Boot application between your changes?

Comment: Yes , ofcourse , I did it not once